# Dynamic Object creat

Tags: java, object, dynamic

I want to create a object in a dynamic manner i use the following code:

```
// Object technical name is xxxx.objectname

String[] ObjectNameArray;   
ObjectNameArray = ObjectName.split(".");

// if the objectname is for exaple deleteme Java should intrpet the code
// as follows deleteme DeletebleObject = new deleteme(getContext());

ObjectNameArray[1] DeletebleObject = new ObjectNameArray[1](getContext());
```

Is this possible? and how can this be achieved?

Thx in advance.

Comment: you got your naming conventions backwards

Comment: You should read the Tutorial about the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via java reflection:

```
    String[] objectNameArray;   
    objectNameArray = objectName.split(".");

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(objectNameArray[1]);
        Object context = getContext();
        Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor( context.getClass() );
        Object instance = constructor.newInstance( context );

    } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( SecurityException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( NoSuchMethodException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( InstantiationException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( IllegalAccessException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch( InvocationTargetException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any way you will need to write a list of class files to create dynamic objects. What I will do is I create a Map which holds the class name as the key and the object as the value. They I call the map and get the object.

Answer (score 0):

1. you got your naming conventions backwards.
2. not sure if thats what you meant but you can get a class instance from it's name using:

   `Class.forName("deleteMe").newInstance();`

assuming your class has an empty constructor.
if you want to use a parameterized constructor:

```
Class.forName("deleteMe").getConstructor(...).newInstance(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use generics here... e.g.

```
    MyClass <T extends Object>
```

Then you can use the wildcard to access them without caring of their type.

```
    MyClass<?> myClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use Factory Design pattern to create Dynamic Objects of Different types by 
>       sending Name

for Refference Link [Factory Desing Pattern](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_sTrTj4nImJ8/TRh1lDMQfSI/AAAAAAAAAAc/6yW0pvAjbMI/s1600/factory1.jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you should look at Java "reflection" mechanisms and create/call dynamically the Object/Method you need. See the following example:

```
// - specifies which class (className) is to be loaded (e.g.: com.example.objectname)
Class<?> loca = Class.forName(className);
// - specifies method (methodName) to be used (e.g.: getContext)
// - assumes the method returns a "String" (String.class)
Method method = loca.getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{String.class});
// - creates a new instance of the class, i.e., an object
Object obj = loca.newInstance();
// - call the actual method in the function
String result = (String) method.invoke(obj, inputParameters);
```

Hope it helps.